# Creating a PowerShell cmdlet in .NET Core 2.0

Tags: powershell, .net-core, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to create a PowerShell commandlet (cmdlet) in .NET Core 2.0.

I have referenced the 'System.Management.Automation' 4.3.0 package and created a simple cmdlet:

```
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace CrudGenerator.PowerShell
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Add, "CrudOperation")]
    public class CrudOperation : Cmdlet
    {
    }

    public enum OperationType
    {
        Get,
        Put,
        Post,
        Delete,
        Search
    }
}
```

Which is working fine.

As soon as I add a parameter I get an exception:

```
Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module .\CrudGenerator.PowerShell.dll
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

for:

```
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace CrudGenerator.PowerShell
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Add, "CrudOperation")]
    public class CrudOperation : Cmdlet
    {
        [Parameter]
        public OperationType Operation { get; set; }
    }

    public enum OperationType
    {
        Get,
        Put,
        Post,
        Delete,
        Search
    }
}
```

I also created the same code in a .NET 4.6.1 class library and then it works like a charm.

Comment: `Import-Module` does not *like* dynamic paths.  Try fully specifying the path in your import statement.  Additionally, create a module manifest for your dll using `New-ModuleManifest`

Comment: When using the full path to the module it still gives the same exception.

Comment: Did you try creating a module manifest?

Comment: I also did. But it still does not work.

Comment: I take it you're not running this on [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v6.0.0-beta.1)? PowerShell runs on the .NET Framework, not .NET Core. You can't expect .NET Core code to run on .NET Framework (and apparently even .NET Standard is a stretch for PowerShell).

Comment: You are right. I did use the normal powershell desktop. So if I compile powershell core and try to run the script on that It should work?

Comment: I have no idea since I haven't actually tried PowerShell Core yet -- I just know you can't run .NET Core code on the .NET Framework. Why not be a pioneer yourself? :-)